# Replace multiple words from a String based on the values in an Array

Tags: swift, string

I have an array of string and another string:

```
let array = ["one","two","three"]
let string = "one two three four five six seven"
```

What is a Swifty way of removing occurrences found in the array from the string? I tried a for loop, but wanted to see if filter would work in such a case?

Comment: If you remove the occurrences what's going to happen with the whitespace characters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395980/how-to-remove-specific-characters-or-words-from-a-string-in-swift

Answer (score 5):

I believe the kind of `filter` expression you're thinking of is this:

```
let finalString = string
    .split(separator: " ")  // Split them
    .lazy                   // Maybe it's very long, and we don't want intermediates
    .map(String.init)       // Convert to the same type as array
    .filter { !array.contains($0) } // Filter
    .joined(separator: " ") // Put them back together
```

Comment: You could get rid of the `.map` if you just did `!array.contains(String($0)`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth  I did that originally, and edited to use the map. It think the map is more beautiful and explicit, when combined with lazy. But I agree, they're very similar, and it's more a matter of style than substance.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4.2 there is a `removeAll(where:` API.

```
let array = ["one","two","three"]
let string = "one two three four five six seven"

var components = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
components.removeAll{array.contains($0)}
let result = components.joined(separator: " ") // "four five six seven"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Efficient solution

The following is an efficient solution that replaces the occurrence of an element in `array`, plus its surrounding spaces, with one space only:

```
let array = ["one","two","three"]
let str = "  eight one  four two   three five   six seven "
var result = ""

var i = str.startIndex

while i < str.endIndex {
    var j = i
    while j < str.endIndex, str[j] == " " {
        j = str.index(after: j)
    }
    var tempo1 = ""
    if i != j { tempo1 += str[i..<j] }

    if j < str.endIndex { i = j } else {
        result += tempo1
        break
    }

    while j < str.endIndex, str[j] != " " {
        j = str.index(after: j)
    }

    let tempo2 = String(str[i..<j])

    if !array.contains(tempo2) {
        result += tempo1 + tempo2
    }

    i = j
}

print(result)  //␣␣eight␣four␣five␣␣␣six␣seven␣
```

The symbol `␣` represents a space.

---

### Benchmarks

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVZLb9tIDL77VzBCgdioquwWewqaQ9oiQBa73aLp7iXpYSxRDp15KDMjO26Qv16XM3rm0WwaVIdAJvmRHz9yRnFrKv0f2y2pylgPR6bWhfBk9GQykehBWCs2cACnidGYpIlfm/D33CImX2KE85b0gkMSgL@MRQVUuVpBYaSxwPEgFPoUGA8RBxpzdI4815nXDvgNhM/gX1dDJaznDE7o3LMroDWm7G6hl7VwwEwt24XK4APGvHiFNieoXZ223oBsIOfkAEUKSkh@Y7JeaAJTlpQTG/IaFMoMjgsoSKgWtKKrNOZA5mRJCXbmzNPRQlOJtlaXNfOq2kqiYuLILLXJ4F0NHGW8iNRWpDhTbLrNLcWcZQrODJLJpDBwPZkAP42arACL@V54nM4a@0pYyA0PSKP2jp2N5NlgmzpkAgwp3m72eRDJLAKHgIznYlZ4KOV1nChjtRek3fTFb7ObvrpFV8tQfoRcGtJYdBWMbfP3GNTFHb4smPbT5D/BguqzXQf7Zz5JQ2DmSeGx9mhXQp6QznEaG56lbekUkjPN2W8AWmUeE2Zv753RK7T9EnrTLGwvW2M/jEv8ROHazJ@iYIASVVS9tEaBsbQgLeSoyrjCwfhXVpLkRuEadu5LDjcPd9DkmYv8IvTS2HoJylD6pDtu41LPntGfH@HwsiZtnjqmEYd@Vk@Y1I/oR2d4MldJ8nc7CALBSfDw2UE1REvxdQP3H47@W2zmCOS5H9Z1A9IEpoIFWCPfSXrXw1poDxTaU8gr6tENiZWopg3HjDT52ZC4G5QPFwvyFaX4PttUCHwjDesQkzw@@ZDsKEYMiIcHGCI/1k3v3VIskH/ZJ4z2k5nDB1ER2l8w2x8NN5j7w9bfHkkyXFw0HLuIPdYFXjXu9TlJHhW86QKYXnS3y9SlWHIK6i0NankflbaG0@UXOAifo2SUJzzLgQoFwFSULMM@LGd92M2twvwpqszvTUOdnUpmvHPAya47/8su7Sll2Ruu3h7uNnz5UINRlyUvA0qHd3i2OnLapsAt55y/Mxcjvj@ny86zdelfwxZEXq8Z1mzL9Fb7s1vd3z0CDXT2Py3Dy7bGQwyidJOR8dFz8Dn8A8Dr/4xv0Hb7LS@lWLjtq3@@Aw)

```
Vadian's      : 0.000336s
JP Aquino's   : 0.000157s
Rob Napier's  : 0.000147s
This Solution : 0.000028s
```

This is at least 5 times faster than any other solution.

---

### Leaving spaces intact

If you don't want to remove spaces (since they're not part of the original array), then this will do:

```
let array = ["one","two","three"]
let str = "one two three four five six seven "
var result = ""

var i = str.startIndex

while i < str.endIndex {
    var j = i
    while j < str.endIndex, str[j] == " " {
        j = str.index(after: j)
    }

    if i != j { result += str[i..<j] }
    if j < str.endIndex { i = j } else { break }

    while j < str.endIndex, str[j] != " " {
        j = str.index(after: j)
    }

    let tempo = String(str[i..<j])

    if !array.contains(tempo) {
        result += tempo
    }

    i = j
}

print(result)   //␣␣␣four five six seven␣
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = ["one","two","three"]
let string = "one two three four five six seven"

//Convert string to array
var stringArray  = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

//Remove elements from original array
stringArray = stringArray.filter { !array.contains($0) }

//Convert stringArray back to string
let finalString = stringArray.joined(separator: " ")
print(finalString)// prints "four five six seven"
```